# Editing / reviewing - understanding change highlighting

Tags: discussion, review

When reviewing edits it often appears that the two versions are identical. Clearly something must have changed as blocks of text / code will be marked as red/green between versions but scanning through doesn't show any change.

1. What would cause this?
2. Should these be approved / rejected / ignored?

Comment: Use the **markdown diffs** radio button to skip out identical lines and see just want was edited. Or the editor may have just added/removed tags (if it is an edit of a question).

Comment: In case the user really did not add anything of course the proper action is to reject as "too minor". Do you have any concrete example?